# window.open object is null after user opens blocked popup

Tags: javascript, popup, window, setinterval, window.open

How can I find out that blocked popup window was opened by the user? I tried to use `setInterval` but the window object is still null even though user manually opened the blocked popup by clicking the blocked popup link

Comment: Since it happens asynchronously, it's not possible for it to reassign the variable.

Comment: but is there any way to find out that user has opened blocked popup?

Comment: @Barmar but is there any way to find out that user has opened blocked popup during current session?

Comment: I can't find a way, but all my google searches about popup blockers return posts about detecting the popup, not opening the window.